# How to append arguments to launch an application with specific parameters from Unity Dash or shortcuts?

Tags: launcher, chromium, shortcuts, ssl

I need to append parameters to Chromium launch in order to disable SSL v3 due to recent  vulnerability refered as [Poodle](https://zmap.io/sslv3/browsers.html#chrome-other):

```
--ssl-version-min=tls1
```

How can I add this parameter in order to:

- Launch Chromium from the default Unity Launcher/Dash
- Preserve this setting after Chromium update/upgrade
- Preserve this setting after Ubuntu update/upgrade

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add this option to the `chromium-browser.desktop` file, but not the one located in `/usr/share/applications/` as this one will be overwritten by package upgrades or release updates.

1. Open a terminal and copy the `/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop` file to your `$XDG_DATA_HOME` folder:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Edit all `Exec=` commands to append the `--ssl-version-min=tls1` option.

   I've found 4 `Exec=` commands in chromium-browser.desktop:

   ```
   $ grep Exec chromium-browser.desktop
   chromium-browser.desktop:Exec=chromium-browser %U
   chromium-browser.desktop:Exec=chromium-browser
   chromium-browser.desktop:Exec=chromium-browser --incognito
   chromium-browser.desktop:Exec=chromium-browser --temp-profile
   ```

   Use the following command to add the ssl option:

   ```
   perl -i -pe 's/(Exec=chromium-browser)/$1 --ssl-version-min=tls1/g' ~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
   ```

   The `Exec` commands now look like:

   ```
   $ grep Exec chromium-browser.desktop
   chromium-browser.desktop:Exec=chromium-browser --ssl-version-min=tls1 %U
   chromium-browser.desktop:Exec=chromium-browser --ssl-version-min=tls1
   chromium-browser.desktop:Exec=chromium-browser --ssl-version-min=tls1 --incognito
   chromium-browser.desktop:Exec=chromium-browser --ssl-version-min=tls1 --temp-profile
   ```

Now the .`desktop` version in your `$HOME` will always take precedence over the one installed in `/usr/share` making the change permanent.

Note that you may have to unlock the icon from the launcher and lock it again to select the right `.desktop` file tough.

To check that the new setting works correctly, type the following command in a terminal:

```
$ ps -aef | grep ssl-version-min | head -n 1
sylvain   4405  2375  0 11:36 ?        00:00:05 chromium-browser --enable-pinch --ssl-version-min=tls1
```

You should see your `chromium-browser` process and its new command line arguments.

Comment: $XDG_DATA_HOME variable is empty. Does it mean that according to the specification the default value for $XDG_DATA_HOME is $HOME/.local/share? Note the OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @g0lem exactly,it will defaut to `$HOME/.local/share`. did you try my proposal?

Comment: @Sylvain_Pineau it works like a charm, thanks. Any specific reason to use perl for inserting content in a text file as shown in your example rather than other Linux command in that case?

Comment: @g0lem not really, perl is my favorite swiss-army knife but sed is also possible of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by adding it `/etc/chromium-browser/default`

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--ssl-version-min=tls1"
```

But modern versions of chromium should be protected against this with insecure versions of SSL removed.